# How can I check if a message handler has already been registered for a ServiceClient instance?

Tags: azureservicebus

How can I check if a message handler has already been registered with a SubscriptionClient instance?

I have the following code:

```
subscriptionClient.RegisterMessageHandler(processMessageAsync, msgOptions)
```

Answer (score 0):

An `InvalidOperationException` will be thrown as you should not be registering more than a single callback. To process multiple messages **concurrently**, `MessageHandlerOptions.MaxConcurrentCalls` should be used.

> How can I check if a message handler has already been registered with a SubscriptionClient instance?

I would suggest tracking handler/callback registration in your code. If that's not possible at all, `try/catch` is an option.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use your SubscriptionClient on a timer loop, you may have to inject the instance in Transient way(AddTransient).

*builder.Services.AddTransient(IServiceProvider => new SubscriptionClient(....));*